# MVC2 Entity Framework - Update Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

First of all, am I the only developer on the planet that is attempting to use MVC with VB?  I have searched tons of forums and read many posts and everyone that asks a question gives an example in C#.  Anyway, now that I've got that out of the way, I've got a simple database table (User) with some columns (UserId, Username, FirstName, LastName).  I am using the entity framework and on my edit view, I'm changing a value (Username) and clicking Save.  In my Edit http post, I tell it to return to the Index and the value was not saved.  Although, in my constructor for the http post, I return the object and it shows the new value...but that value doesn't make it to the db...any help?

My Controller:

```
Function Edit(ByVal ID As Guid) As ActionResult
        'get the user
        Dim usr = (From u In db.Users
                  Where u.UserId = ID
                  Select u).Single

        Return View(usr)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function Edit(ByVal ID As Guid, ByVal usrInfo As User, ByVal formValues As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        '            Dim usr As User = db.Users.Single(Function(u) u.UserId = ID)

        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            TryUpdateModel(usrInfo, "User")

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Else
            Return View(usrInfo)
        End If
    End Function
```

My view:

```
    <h2>Edit</h2>

<%-- The following line works around an ASP.NET compiler warning --%>
<%: ""%>

<% Using Html.BeginForm() %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(True) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserId) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserId) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserId) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Username) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Username) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Username) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FirstName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.FirstName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.FirstName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.LastName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.LastName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.LastName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CreatedDate) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.CreatedDate, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.CreatedDate)) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CreatedDate) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CreatedBy) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.CreatedBy) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CreatedBy) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.LastLogin) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.LastLogin, String.Format("{0:g}", Model.LastLogin)) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.LastLogin) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% End Using %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, aparently I AM the only VB developer using MVC.  Anyway, I found the answer.  It was in one of the beginner tutorials for MVC on the ASP.Net Site ([Found Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs)).  The answer was to change my Edit function (HttpPost) so that it utilizes the formvalues that were posted:

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Function Edit(ByVal id As Guid, ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Dim rest = (From r In db.Restaurants
                Where r.RestaurantId = id
                Select r).Single()

        Try

            TryUpdateModel(rest, collection.ToValueProvider())

            db.SaveChanges()

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Catch
            Return View(rest)
        End Try
    End Function
```